# How to validate params in REST Lumen/Laravel request?

Tags: laravel, validation, url, get, lumen

Route:
`$app->get('/ip/{ip}', GeoIpController::class . '@show');`

How to validate ip's properly? I've tried to inject `Request` object in `show` method, but wasn't able to solve this. I want to stick with `REST`, so using `URL` parameters is not solution for me. I use it for `API` purposes, so status code as response would be appropriate.

Also tried that way:

```
$app->bind('ip', function ($ip) {
    $this->validate($ip, [
        'ip' => 'required|ip',
    ]);
});
```

EDIT:
The answer below is correct, I've found more info about `requests` in documentation:

> Form requests are not supported by Lumen. If you would like to use form requests, you should use the full Laravel framework.

In other words, you cannot use custom `requests` via injection in constructors in Lumen.

Comment: What's the problem with https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-ip ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `validate` method takes the request object as the first parameter. Since you're passing the ip in the route, you need to create a custom validator.

```
public function show($ip)
{
    $data = ['ip' => $ip];

    $validator = \Validator::make($data, [
        'ip' => 'required|ip'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $validator->errors();
    }

    return response()->json(['All good!']);
}
```

Edit : This is all laravel does under the hood. You could basically you this function directly to validate the ip and save a lot of effort.

```
protected function validateIp($ip)
{
    return filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) !== false;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. One more question is: in `Lumen`, which I use in this project, there is no available class `\Validator`, and `Illuminate\Validation\Validator` does not provide `make` method. Property `$app->withFacades();` is enabled.

Comment: I've use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;` and it works like a gold. Thank you.

Comment: @wujt that's good and i added the validation function in case you need to. Basic ip validation doesn't need much effort.